# How to change the time in "The Crew" online?

Tags: the-crew

The Crew has a standard day/night cycle like most online games.

I'm sure I've seen it jump around (go from middle of night to day time), but I'm not sure how or why.

Does using the travel menu (trains/ planes), fast travel or workshops change the time?

I would really like to be able to skip night sometimes & play during day time so I don't miss out on the scenery.

Is it possible to change the time in "The Crew" or trigger a time change somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only place where you can change the time of the day is in the Photography mode.

While online, it shows the same time for every player and this is not changeable. The time of day changes traffic patterns somewhat, so it has to be the same for every player.